# Using MoPi power board with RuneAudio (simbamond installation)

Tags: power, power-supply, audio-playback

I would like to power my Pi running Runeaudio with a MoPi power board.
However, it is designed to work with Raspbian, and the installation of the `simbamond` package is required.

Since Runeaudio is based on ArchLinux, the ordinary `sudo apt-get simbamond` wont work.

I tried to use `pacman -S`, but I think that `simbamond` is not available at all.

Is there a way to have such a function?

Comment: You can't really excpect Arch's package manager `pacman` to run smoothly on Raspbian. Could you install your software from source?

Comment: I don't want to use pacman on raspbian, rather to install `simbamond` (available in raspbian) on runeaudio